# Catch All Regex for Several URL Strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to craft a regex that would match

```
/strategies/createStrategy
```

or

```
/strategies/updateStrategy
```

in the follwing cases

```
/strategies/createStrategy/:step?
/strategies/updateStrategy/:id/:step?
/strategies/createStrategy/basic-info
```

I want to put a capture group around the matched section and use it in a string comparison. I've done some experimentation with negative lookahead but no matter what I seem to do I lose the match on either the second or last item. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you need negative lookahead for?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I guess nothing,  a guide I followed for something similar used negative look ahead

Comment: Use positive lookahead instead, for the final `/`? `\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+(?=\/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^((\/\w+)*)(?=\/)` [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3t46g)

- Look for `/...` as 0-infinite times (as often as possible) `((\/\w+)*)`
- Match only until ending slash `(?=\/)` (positive lookahead)